# What is causing this Python pandas matplotlib time shift?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

In the following code example, note that the only difference between the data for the first and the second plot is the time series. `ts1` is used on the `b` data series in the first and `ts2` is used on the `b` data series in the second.

And the only difference between the time series is the hour of the first and the last day. If I change either to `10` (as in `ts1`), the problem disappears.

The code:

```
    from datetime import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

    f = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

    data1 = [1, 2, 3]
    data2 = [4, 3, 2]
    ts1 = [datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 10:00:00', f), datetime.strptime('2000-01-02 10:00:00', f), datetime.strptime('2000-01-03 10:00:00', f)]
    ts2 = [datetime.strptime('2000-01-01 09:00:00', f), datetime.strptime('2000-01-02 10:00:00', f), datetime.strptime('2000-01-03 11:00:00', f)]

    a1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, ts1, ['a'])
    a2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, ts1, ['b'])

    b1 = pd.DataFrame(data1, ts1, ['a'])
    b2 = pd.DataFrame(data2, ts2, ['b'])

    fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(15, 5))

    a1.plot(ax=axs[0], color='r')
    a2.plot(ax=axs[0].twinx())

    b1.plot(ax=axs[1], color='r')
    b2.plot(ax=axs[1].twinx())

    axs[2].plot(ts1, data1, color='r')
    axs[2].twinx().plot(ts2, data2)

    fig.tight_layout()
    fig.savefig('../output/plottest.png', format='png')
```

The output:
[image: Note the weird output for the middle image]]

What is causing pandas to shift the `a` series to 2053 or thereabouts in the center plot, just because a single hour value changes? This problem is driving me up the walls... I've tried using `pd.Timestamp` instead, but that changes nothing.

I included the third plot to show that a basic plot of the same data using only matplotlib does not appear to have this problem, so it would appear this is a problem with my use of pandas? Or a bug in pandas DataFrame.plot function?

Edit:

My used requirements.txt with this script, running on 3.6.3 64-bit Python on Windows:

```
    backports.functools-lru-cache==1.4
    cycler==0.10.0
    matplotlib==2.1.0
    numpy==1.13.3
    pandas==0.21.0
    pyparsing==2.2.0
    python-dateutil==2.6.1
    pytz==2017.2
    six==1.11.0
```

Installed through `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: The strange thing is that even if you only change the first item of `ts3` to one second later, it will already work, `2000-01-01 09:00:01`.

Comment: Huh, that's interesting too... (I made an edit, your comment makes sense to me, but I simplified the example, so I get that you mean to say ```ts2``` - sorry). You're right, I can replicate that result. Crazy.

Comment: I guess the problem is the `twinx`. It could be that pandas date locators are not capable of being "twinned". You could open an issue on the pandas issue tracker about this.

Comment: FWIW, I can't reproduce this exact bug: when I plot it, `a` is not shown on the middle plot, and the date tick marks are screwy. pandas 0.21.

Comment: Yes, true, using pandas 0.20 the plot does come out a bit differently than shown in the question; the main point is still that the data is not shown correctly. @Evan you may probably find the other line by panning up to the year 2053.

Comment: I'm adding used library versions to the question, in case more people experience difficulty reproducing (or find a version of the libraries that doesn't have this issue)

Comment: Note that this item is now also registered as an issue on the pandas issue tracker. https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18571